# No class found in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, soap

i imported my projected from eclipse to android studio it was working fine and in android studio it works in emulator but in real device

here is log

> 05-04 08:14:14.989 8986-9070/com.rcmbusiness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                  Process: com.rcmbusiness, PID: 8986
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
>                                                                      at com.rcmbusiness.utility.APIRequest.doInBackground(APIRequest.java:113)
>                                                                      at com.rcmbusiness.utility.APIRequest.doInBackground(APIRequest.java:29)
>                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'


compile files('libs/AndroidAnimations.jar')
compile files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')

compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-       dependencies.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, You should remove ksoap in Project Structure and do the steps bellow.
I have same problem and here is the way which work for me.
1st: Make folder libs in app/libs.
2nd: Copy ksoap.jar to this folder.
3rd: right click to Jar file and chose add as library.
Then, import ksoap2 normally way.

Comment: Thank you for reply but libs folder already in app folder and am using android studio so when i click on jar file then i do not get option to add as library